# Calculate the area of intersection between the circles below as a function of A1 and A2.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:In the figure, calculate the area of intersection between the circles as a function of $A1$ and $A2$.
$OT = TO1$

[image]

My progress

$S=S_1+S_2\\
A_1 = \pi R^2\\
A_2 =\pi r^2\\
R=2r \therefore A_1 = \pi (2r)^2 = 4r^2\pi\\
S_1=S_{GEO_1F}=S_{OEO_1F}-S\triangle_{OEF}=S_{OEO_1F}-\frac{EF.GO}{2}\\
S_2=S_{GFTE}=S_{TEO_1F}-S\triangle_{_1OEF}= S_{TEO_1F}-\frac{EF.GO_1}{2}\\
S_1+S_2 = S_{OEO_1F}-\frac{EF.GO}{2}+ S_{TEO_1F}-\frac{EF.GO_1}{2}=
S_{OEO_1F}+S_{TEO_1F}-\frac{EF}{2}(\underbrace{GO_1+GO}_R)$

...???

[image]

Comment: I do not understand why it asks in terms of $A_1$ and $A_2$ when $A_1 = 4 A_2$

Comment: @Physor $R = 2r$, so $A_1 = 4 A_2$

Comment: If I understand OP's work, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are areas of the circles but if $O_1$ is the center of the smaller circle then radius of the bigger circle is double of the smaller circle. Anyway I will let OP clarify.

Comment: Oh! the $A$s are areas ? sorry, I thought them radii!

Comment: @MathLover I didn't understand either but I believe that in the solution it won't turn A1 into A2 or vice versa

Comment: @MathLover book answer is $\frac{A1 - 4A2}{3}$ but Iit's wrong  $\frac{\pi}{3}.[ R^2-4(\frac{R}{2})^2] = 0$

Comment: What is not clear in my answer ?

Comment: @Physor  The answer must be in function of A1 and A2

Comment: The two areas you mentioned are related, as in the comments above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the answer key you provided (in comments), it seems you have misunderstood the question. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not the areas of full circles, they are areas of the crescents!

[image]

With this hint, you can find the answer easily.

> $$A+A_1=4\pi r^2$$ $$A+A_2=\pi r^2$$ where $r$ is the radius of smaller circle. Find $A$.

Comment: $2A = 5\pi r^2 - (A1+A2)$ but $A1+A2 = 5 \pi r^2  \implies A = 0$ ???

Comment: @petaarantes ... please see the edited answer. Do you understand how I got the two formulas?

Comment: I understod but which edited answer? put your complet answer

Comment: (+1) @peta arantes The interpretation of Random visitor looks the good one: area $A_1$ and $A_2$ should be interpreted as the two crescents" areas. Then multiplying his second equation by 4 and then subtracting to it the first equation to the second gives tha answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie  grateful for the explanation... now I understand perfectly